# How to implement a batch linear link in chainer, that supports different weights for every example in batch?

Tags: python, chainer

We use `chainer.functions.linear` to compute `y=Wx+b`.

In my case, I have to implement a linear link with one more dimension.

Say the input example is `(c, x)`, the desired output is then `y = W_c x + b`. Let's ignore the bias and make it `y = W_c x`.
The cardinal number of `{c}` is known in advance (usually classes of samples).

Theoretically the `W` parameter can be implemented as a 3-d tensor `(C, y_dims, x_dims)`. But what else? Do I have to iterate over the batch and extract `W_c` in shape `(y_dims, x_dims)` and call `functions.linear` merely for that `(1, x_dims)`-shaped example?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I myself found one solution to the question.

Let the data be of shapes as follows,

- `W: (C, y_dims, x_dims)`
- `x: (batch, x_dims)`
- `c: (batch, 1)`

First I have to get a weight matrix for every x in batch:

```
W_c = chainer.functions.get_item(W, chainer.as_variable(c).data)
y = chainer.functions.batch_matmul(W_c, chainer.expand_dims(x, 2)) // in shape (batch, y_dims, 1)
```

So the key function here is `get_item` which accepts both `numpy.ndarray` and `cupy.ndarray` but **NOT** `chainer.Variable`. It works like `numpy.take` but is differentiable and saves a lot of work.